# WP-Customizer changes not appearing

Tags: wordpress

My problem is that when I'm making changes to my themes in the wp-customizer to my sites, those changes doesn't get applied. When I click on the site button on the dashboard, it says missed planning. I've tried this on several themes, including the actual theme of my site Oasis, as well as Twety Twenty and Twenty Nineteen. I tried this on WP-Versions 5.3, 5.4, 5.5. Furthermore I've checked the timezone and other settings. I havent't installed any plugins and WP is installed freshly, multiple times.

When I'm trying to open the customizer, I'm getting an error, the title says Wordpress-Error and the page displays that my scheduled changes have been published, which as I described above, isn't the case. The console of this error page outputs no errors, even though the debugging mode is enabled.

Comment: Try publishing it without scheduling, just publishing it immediately after making a change

Comment: I did. I tried both publishing directly, as well as scheduling...

Comment: Are you 100% sure you aren't missing any file? Are you 100% sure that you can actually see all the errors (WP_DEBUG true may not be enough)? Are you 100% you have nothing in console? Have you tried viewing the source code of the customizer page (not with developer tools, go check the pure HTML) and see if something is cutting your page render?

Comment: Yes, I'mabsolutely sure, No Errors